# can not login to website using mechanize

Tags: python, authentication, mechanize

i want to login to http://nas.ub.ac.id/webAuth/ using mechanize

it is the form
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-xD337tAg6mE/U2eDbrTnsZI/AAAAAAAAEuo/P42DQqjHgBQ/w676-h200-no/forms.PNG

it is my code

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://nas.ub.ac.id/webAuth")
br.select_form(nr = 0)
br.form['username'] = "my username"
br.form['password'] = "my password"
br.submit()
```

do you know why is it not succesfully to login. thanks

Comment: The website appears to be down.

Comment: no, i can login manually with browser.
the website is on my local university network
.

Do you know the meaning of readonly in the form ?https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-xD337tAg6mE/U2eDbrTnsZI/AAAAAAAAEuo/P42DQqjHgBQ/w676-h200-no/forms.PNG

Comment: I think you are seeing a cached version of the website and not the current state of the website. Try loading the website then using Ctrl + F5. 

http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ also indicated that the website is down.

Comment: sorry, it just can access from my local university network.
it is the snapshot https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-fD03O5hiWuM/U2eHyjyjKxI/AAAAAAAAEvU/EAFaoI_ZNaE/w1044-h513-no/tampilan.PNG